# Google Visualization - Highlight data in a Table

Tags: google-visualization

I am a beginner to the Google Visualization .I have made a dashboard with google visualization. My dashboard has a table that is drawn with the help of ChartWrapper and I filter the table by one of the columns with the help of String filter. Please check the below how my script look like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['controls']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization() {
        // Prepare the data.
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Name', 'Age'],
          ['Michael' , '17'],
          ['Elisa', '17'],
          ['Robert', '17'],
          ['John', '17'],
          ['Jessica', '18'],
          ['Aaron', '19'],
          ['Margareth', '17'],
          ['Miranda', '15']
        ]);

        // Define a StringFilter control for the 'Name' column
        var stringFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'StringFilter',
          'containerId': 'control1',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Name'
          }
        });

        // Define a table visualization
        var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'Table',
          'containerId': 'chart1',
          'options': {'height': '13em', 'width': '20em'}

        });

        // Create the dashboard.
        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).
          // Configure the string filter to affect the table contents
          bind(stringFilter, table).
          // Draw the dashboard
          draw(data);
      }


      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
```

But i want to highlight all the rows  in "red" color within the table , where the age of a person is not equal to 17 . So can anyone please help me in doing this.

Many Thanks in Advance

Comment: Here, add formatter ranges https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#colorformatter

Answer (score 0):

Use the color formatter syntax to specify your range and style.

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.ColorFormat();
formatter.addRange(null, 17, 'white', 'red');
formatter.addRange(17, null, 'white', 'red');
formatter.format(data, 1);
```

This will search for values from -∞ to 17 and 17 to +∞ but does not include 17 since it is non-inclusive. But this will only color the cell but not the entire row. You can possibly use another hack to color the rest of the cells in the row.